# Open Source Full Disk Encryption for BSD Operating System?

Tags: encryption, filesystems, freebsd, bsd

Anyone aware of an open source equivalent to full disk encryption products such as Pointsec (a Check Point product) where the machine won't boot unless a password is supplied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software), I see the following disk encryption methods that are can be used on BSD (FreeBSD or NetBSD):

- [CGD](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-cgd.html) (NetBSD)
- [GBDE](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/disks-encrypting.html) (FreeBSD)
- [GELI](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/disks-encrypting.html) (FreeBSD)

Comment: On FreeBSD, GBDE seems to have fallen out of favor somewhat compared to GELI.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD, you can encrypt *almost* the whole disk. If you want to encrypt the partition containing the filesystem root, you need an unencrypted partition to contain `/boot`.

On a bog-standard FreeBSD 9 install, `/boot` is around 300 MB. Most of that is `/boot/kernel`, especially the `symbols` files for the kernel and modules.

See e.g. [this blog article](https://www.dan.me.uk/blog/2012/05/05/full-disk-encryption-in-freebsd-9-x-well-almost/).

Personally, I wouldn't bother encrypting more than the partition that holds your data. There is nothing secret in the OS files itself.

Comment: could you maybe provide a link or something? :)

Answer (score 0):

Truecrypt supports windows, linux and mac. It supports [full disk encryption](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=system-encryption), although that is listed as supported only for windows. There [apparently](http://it.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=606473&cid=24099195) [exists](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=3183) some patches that adds support for freebsd, although I do not know if that includes 
full disk encryption.

In a comment to [this blog](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/07/truecrypts_deni.html) post by Bruce Schneier, the following is mentioned in addition to the ones already listed in Rick Copeland's answer:

- svnd (OpenBSD)

and maybe

- EncFS
- CryptoFS